# Running functions in parallel

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2012, functions

This is for SQL Server 2012.

We have some import processes for FTP files that are picked up and read into a staging table, from there we massage/check the data before moving into production.  One of the areas that are causing some issues is dates, some are valid, some are typos, some are just plain gibberish.

I have the following example table(s):

```
Create Table RawData
(
 InsertID int not null,
 MangledDateTime1 varchar(10) null,
 MangledDateTime2 varchar(10) null,
 MangledDateTime3 varchar(10) null
)
```

I also have a destination table(say in production)

```
Create Table FinalData
(
  PrimaryKeyID int not null, -- PK constraint here, ident
  ForeighKeyID int not null, -- points to InsertID of RawData
  ValidDateTime1 SmallDateTime null,
  ValidDateTime2 SmallDateTime null,
  ValidDateTime3 SmallDateTime null
)
```

I insert the following into the RawData table:

```
 Insert Into RawData(InsertID, MangledDateTime1, MangledDateTime2, MangledDateTime3)
 Values(1, '20001010', '20800630', '00000000') -- First is legit, second two are not
 Insert Into RawData(InsertID, MangledDateTime1, MangledDateTime2, MangledDateTime3)
 Values(1, '20800630', '20130630', '20000000') -- middle is legit, first/third are not
 Insert Into RawData(InsertID, MangledDateTime1, MangledDateTime2, MangledDateTime3)
 Values(1, '00001010', '00800630', '20130630') -- Last is legit, first two are not
```

I wrote a function `dbo.CreateDate` to address the issue(s). We try to clean the data as best we can (use `NULL` if we can't), then convert the data to the correct datatype (in this case `smalldatetime`).

```
Insert Into FinalData(ForeighKeyID , ValidDateTime1, ValidDateTime2, ValidDateTime3)
Select 
 InsertID
 ,dbo.CreateDate(MangledDateTime1)
 ,dbo.CreateDate(MangledDateTime2)
 ,dbo.CreateDate(MangledDateTime3)
From RawData
```

We're running into some performance problems with functions.  I'm wondering if/how they work in parallel.

I'm **assuming** here that the function `CreateDate` is being run in parallel as each row inserts.  Such that each column/value has it's "own" function and is running at the same time as it inserts.

But I could be wrong, is it running serial over each column in each row as it inserts?

#### CreateDate() code:

```
Alter Function dbo.CreateDate
(
@UnformattedString  varchar(12)
)
Returns smalldatetime
As
Begin
Declare @FormattedDate smalldatetime

If(@UnformattedString Is Not Null)
Begin
    Declare @MaxSmallDate varchar(8) = '20790606'


    -- We got gibberish
    If Len(@UnformattedString) = 1
    Begin
        return null
    End

    -- To account for date and time
    If Len(@UnformattedString) = 12
    Begin
        Select @UnformattedString = Substring(@UnformattedString, 0,9)
    End

    If @UnformattedString = '20000000'
    Begin
        Select @UnformattedSTring = @MaxSmallDate
    End

    -- Some people are sending us two digit years, won't parse right
    If Substring(@UnformattedString,0,3) = '00'
    Begin
        Select @UnformattedString = Replace(@UnformattedString, '00','20')
    End

    -- Some people are fat fingering in people born in 18??, so change to 19??
    If Substring(@UnformattedString,0,3) in ('18')
    Begin
        -- We only want to change the year '18', not day 18 
        SELECT @UnformattedString = STUFF(@UnformattedString, 
                           CHARINDEX('18', @UnformattedString), 2, '19')
    End

    -- We're getting gibberish
    If Substring(@UnformattedString,0,3) not in ('19','20') 
               And Len(@UnformattedString) != 6
    Begin
        Select @UnformattedString = Replace(@UnformattedString, 
                       Substring(@UnformattedString,0,3),'20')
    End

    -- If the 4 digit year is greater than current year, set to max date
    If Convert(int, Substring(@UnformattedString,0,5)) > Year(getdate())
    Begin
        Set @FormattedDate = CONVERT(smalldatetime,@MaxSmallDate,1)
    End
    -- If the 4 digit year is less than 100 years ago, set to max date
    Else If Year(getdate()) - Convert(int, Substring(@UnformattedString,0,5)) >= 100
    Begin
        Set @FormattedDate = CONVERT(smalldatetime,@MaxSmallDate,1)
    End
    Else -- valid date(we hope)
    Begin
        Set @FormattedDate = CONVERT(smalldatetime,@UnformattedString,1) 
    End

    
    
End

Return @FormattedDate
End
Go
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using T-SQL scalar functions will frequently lead to performance problems* because SQL Server makes a separate function call (using a whole new T-SQL context) for each row. In addition, [parallel execution is disallowed for the whole query](http://web.archive.org/web/20180404164406/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/12/23/forcing-a-parallel-query-execution-plan.aspx).

T-SQL scalar functions can also make it difficult to troubleshoot performance problems (whether those problems are caused by the function or not). The function [appears as a 'black box' to the query optimizer](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/conor/sql-server-scalar-operator-costing-aka-umm-what-costing/): it is assigned a fixed low estimated cost, regardless of the actual content of the function.

See [this](http://dataeducation.com/scalar-functions-inlining-and-performance-an-entertaining-title-for-a-boring-post/) and [this](https://sqlserverfast.com/?s=user+defined+ugly) for more on the pitfalls of scalar functions.

You will probably be better off using the new [TRY_CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) function in SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT
    InsertID,
    dt1 = TRY_CONVERT(smalldatetime, MangledDateTime1),
    dt2 = TRY_CONVERT(smalldatetime, MangledDateTime2),
    dt3 = TRY_CONVERT(smalldatetime, MangledDateTime3)
FROM dbo.RawData;

╔══════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ InsertID ║         dt1         ║         dt2         ║         dt3         ║
╠══════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║        1 ║ 2000-10-10 00:00:00 ║ NULL                ║ NULL                ║
║        1 ║ NULL                ║ 2013-06-30 00:00:00 ║ NULL                ║
║        1 ║ NULL                ║ NULL                ║ 2013-06-30 00:00:00 ║
╚══════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

#### After the edit to the question

I see the function contains some specific logic. You could still look to use `TRY_CONVERT` as part of that, but you should definitely convert the scalar function to an in-line function. In-line functions (`RETURNS TABLE`) use a single `SELECT` statement and are expanded into the calling query and fully optimized in much the same way views are. It can be helpful to think of in-line functions as parameterized views.

For example, an approximate translation of the scalar function to an in-line version is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CleanDate
    (@UnformattedString  varchar(12))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
SELECT Result =
    -- Successful conversion or NULL after
    -- workarounds applied in CROSS APPLY
    -- clauses below
    TRY_CONVERT(smalldatetime, ca3.string)
FROM
(
    -- Logic starts here
    SELECT        
        CASE
            WHEN @UnformattedString IS NULL
                THEN NULL
            WHEN LEN(@UnformattedString) <= 1
                THEN NULL
            WHEN LEN(@UnformattedString) = 12
                THEN LEFT(@UnformattedString, 8)
            ELSE @UnformattedString
        END
) AS Input (string)
CROSS APPLY
(
    -- Next stage using result so far
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN @UnformattedString = '20000000' 
            THEN '20790606' 
            ELSE Input.string
        END
) AS ca1 (string)
CROSS APPLY 
(
    -- Next stage using result so far
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN LEFT(ca1.string, 2) = '00' THEN '20' + RIGHT(ca1.string, 6)
        WHEN LEFT(ca1.string, 2) = '18' THEN '19' + RIGHT(ca1.string, 6)
        WHEN LEFT(ca1.string, 2) = '19' THEN ca1.string
        WHEN LEFT(ca1.string, 2) = '20' THEN ca1.string
        WHEN LEN(ca1.string) <> 6 THEN '20' + RIGHT(ca1.string, 6)
        ELSE ca1.string
    END
) AS ca2 (string)
CROSS APPLY
(
    -- Next stage using result so far
    SELECT
        CASE 
            WHEN TRY_CONVERT(integer, LEFT(ca2.string, 4)) > YEAR(GETDATE())
                THEN '20790606'
            WHEN YEAR(GETDATE()) - TRY_CONVERT(integer, LEFT(ca2.string, 4)) >= 100
                THEN '20790606'
            ELSE ca2.string
        END
) AS ca3 (string);
```

The function used on the sample data:

```
SELECT
    InsertID,
    Result1 = CD1.Result,
    Result2 = CD2.Result,
    Result3 = CD3.Result
FROM dbo.RawData AS RD
CROSS APPLY dbo.CleanDate(RD.MangledDateTime1) AS CD1
CROSS APPLY dbo.CleanDate(RD.MangledDateTime2) AS CD2
CROSS APPLY dbo.CleanDate(RD.MangledDateTime3) AS CD3;
```

Output:

```
╔══════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ InsertID ║       Result1       ║       Result2       ║       Result3       ║
╠══════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║        1 ║ 2000-10-10 00:00:00 ║ 2079-06-06 00:00:00 ║ NULL                ║
║        1 ║ 2079-06-06 00:00:00 ║ 2013-06-30 00:00:00 ║ 2079-06-06 00:00:00 ║
║        1 ║ 2000-10-10 00:00:00 ║ 2079-06-06 00:00:00 ║ 2013-06-30 00:00:00 ║
╚══════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

<sub>*CLR scalar functions have a much faster invocation path than T-SQL scalar functions and do not prevent parallelism.</sub>