# Optimising filter with dynamic computed column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, functions, query-performance

I need to implement user risk scoring in model

1. The user risk scoring must compile dynamically on changes (eg: profile, transaction) - meaning for any changes on profile or any incoming transaction, the new risk scoring value needs to be be able to reflect immediately
2. It will span across 10+ different tables
3. The query with user list need to be able to filter by `RiskScore`

#### Options

1. I can create a user defined function `[udf].[CalculateRiskScore]` and make a computed column in `[dbo].[User]` or query out during view
   The advantage with this is good maintainability but bad performance.
2. Another way is to have a trigger for those 10 tables to call `[udf].[CalculateRiskScore]` and update `[RiskScore]` into `[dbo].[tblUser]` with indexing on `[RiskScore]`.
   The advantage with this is good performance but poor maintainability since now i have to repeat x times depending on how many table that will affect `[RiskScore].`

---

There may be another solution I am not aware of. Is there any way that I can get the best of both worlds while adhering to the requirement?

My objective is to call `[udf].[CalculateRiskScore]` in one single place only while not sacrificing performance of filtering user with `[RiskScore]`

Comment: Is there a reason that the logic in the function has to be encapsulated in a UDF?

Comment: Another option is to create a materialized view (indexed views in SQL Server) based on a view that returns the risk score paired with the user primary key.

Comment: @ErikDarling to make it easier to maintain. I couldn't think of other way of easier maintanence other than encapsulating in udf.

Comment: If it's a computed column definition, it's already encapsulated. Changing the column definition, or changing the UDF definition if it's referenced in a computed column is the same thing. Also, look at this Q&A: [Is there a way to prevent Scalar UDFs in computed columns from inhibiting parallelism?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/187342/32281).